# Use jquery to write an ID based on text in a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I am not sure if this is even possible, with that said... below is a sample of HTML I am working with. I want to, with jQuery, grab the product name and insert it as an ID on the paired span tag with the class "support", replacing spaces with underscores.

```
<div><span class="title">Product1 Name</span> <span class="support"></span></div>
<div><span class="title">Product1 Name</span> <span class="support"></span></div>
<div><span class="title">Product1 Name</span> <span class="support"></span></div>
<div><span class="title">Product1 Name</span> <span class="support"></span></div>
```

Below would be the desired HTML that jQuery would modify. Is this possible?

```
<div><span class="title">Product1 Name</span> <span class="support" id="product1_name"></span> </div>
<div><span class="title">Product2 Name</span> <span class="support" id="product2_name"></span> </div>
<div><span class="title">Product3 Name</span> <span class="support" id="product3_name"></span> </div>
<div><span class="title">Product4 Name</span> <span class="support" id="product4_name"></span></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean for your "input" spans to have different product names? They all have `Product1 Name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.

```
$('span.title').each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
    $this.next().attr('id', id);
});
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/PeXu9/1/)

This could very well create elements with duplicate IDs, however. Not good.

Comment: How can this be modified to target the span with a class of "support" in the same div tag? I failed to mention there will be some other span tags in the  mix.

Comment: @Robert: change `$this.next()` to `$this.siblings('span.support')`. http://api.jquery.com/siblings

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
(".title").each(function() {$(this).next(".support").attr("id",$(this).html().replace(" ","_"));});
```

didn't check it but it should work, hope I got the parenthesis count right in the end...